# why flutter static final variable changed

Tags: flutter

I am define a static final variable in flutter using [configuration](https://pub.dev/packages/global_configuration/versions) package like this:

```
class GlobalConfig {
      static final GlobalConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration();
}
```

to my understand, the config should initial once when load the class, then keep the same all the time until close the app. But now the config has different value in app running. It make me sometimes read config success, sometimes failed. This is my full code of GlobalConfig class:

```
import 'package:global_configuration/global_configuration.dart';

enum ConfigType { DEV, PRO }

class GlobalConfig {
  GlobalConfig(this.baseUrl, this.shareUrl, this.staticResourceUrl);

  static final GlobalConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration();
  String baseUrl = config.get("baseUrl");
  String shareUrl = config.get("shareUrl");
  String staticResourceUrl = config.get("staticUrl");

  static getBaseUrl() {
    String configBaseUrl = config.get("baseUrl");
    return configBaseUrl;
  }

  static getShareUrl() {
    return config.get("shareUrl");
  }

  static getStaticResourceUrl() {
    return config.get("staticUrl");
  }

  static getConfig(String key) {
    return config.get(key);
  }

  static init(ConfigType configType) {
    switch (configType) {
      case ConfigType.DEV:
        break;
      case ConfigType.PRO:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

is there any way to make the config keep the same and do not change? or what should I do to make read the config keep stable? I want the config read all success or all failed. this is the success reading when debbuging:

[image]

this is the read faild debbuing:

[image]

the breakpoint was entered after the app configuration loaded complete. BTW, my project is open source, all the source code from [here](https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/flutter-netease-music). The basic logic is when playing music, I send a http request to save the songs info to my own server. the function is: `ReddwarfMusic.savePlayingMusic`, this function read a global config of my own server url. The RM radio page add favirate save reading config success, but auto save from FM radio read config failed. I tried to make the config final static but not fixed it. So I thinking for days and do not know how to make it work.

TRIED:

now I tweak the code like this:

```
import 'package:global_configuration/global_configuration.dart';

enum ConfigType { DEV, PRO }

class GlobalConfig {
  static Map config = Map<String, String>();

  GlobalConfig() {

  }

  static getBaseUrl() {
    String configBaseUrl = config["baseUrl"];
    return configBaseUrl;
  }

  static getShareUrl() {
    return config["shareUrl"];
  }

  static getStaticResourceUrl() {
    return config["staticUrl"];
  }

  static getConfig(String key) {
    return config[key];
  }

  static init(ConfigType configType) {
    var globalConfig = GlobalConfiguration();
    if (globalConfig.appConfig.isNotEmpty) {
      config = Map.unmodifiable(globalConfig.appConfig);
    }
    switch (configType) {
      case ConfigType.DEV:
        break;
      case ConfigType.PRO:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

but the config seems initial every time. First I set the config success, but when I use, the config changed to null.

[image]

this is the initial code:

```
var globalConfig = GlobalConfiguration();
    if (globalConfig.appConfig.isNotEmpty) {
      config = Map.unmodifiable(globalConfig.appConfig);
    }
```

I am sure the initial config success.

Comment: "But now the config has different value in app running." Can you elaborate exactly what you observe and show the code that sees a different value? What does "It make me sometimes read config success, sometimes failed." mean? `final` *will* prevent `GlobalConfig.config` from being reassigned to a different object.  It will not prevent the object from being mutated.

Comment: I have pasted the debbugging UI, is it possible to make the the config immutable after initial? what should I do to make the app get a stable configuration from config? @jamesdlin I do not want to read different value from the config, I want to make the config return keep the same in everytime reading.

Comment: No, there is no way to change a mutable object to an immutable one.  At best you could make your own, unmodifiable copy of the `appConfig` `Map` with the [`Map.unmodifiable` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/Map.unmodifiable.html), and then use that everywhere instead of `GlobalConfiguration.appConfig`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly find one type of invoke was send from background service `pragma` entry point, so the configuration should initial in background service too. This is the entry look like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:music_player/music_player.dart';
import 'package:quiet/app.dart';
import 'package:quiet/component.dart';
import 'package:quiet/repository/netease.dart';
import 'package:wheel/wheel.dart';

void main() {
  CommonUtils.initialApp(ConfigType.PRO).whenComplete(() => {loadApp(ConfigType.PRO)});
}

/// The entry of dart background service
/// NOTE: this method will be invoked by native (Android/iOS)
@pragma('vm:entry-point') // avoid Tree Shaking
void playerBackgroundService() {
  CommonUtils.initialApp(ConfigType.PRO).whenComplete(() => {
    loadRepository()
  });
}

void loadRepository() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  GlobalConfig.init(ConfigType.PRO);
  neteaseRepository = NeteaseRepository();
  runBackgroundService(
    imageLoadInterceptor: BackgroundInterceptors.loadImageInterceptor,
    playUriInterceptor: BackgroundInterceptors.playUriInterceptor,
    playQueueInterceptor: QuietPlayQueueInterceptor(),
  );
}
```

I don't know why the background service could not read the configuration.